# Upload a document after saving it with agility pack fails

Tags: asp.net, html-agility-pack, ftpwebrequest

I've been struggling with some issue with an upload (thru FtpWebRequest) of a document after it's been saved with Html Agility pack.
I'm trying to edit a html file and then save it to a stringWriter and then upload it to a server.
I'm saving the document like this
    ...

```
doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = True
doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = True
Dim sr As New StringWriter
doc.Save(sr)
```

And then upload it using asyncFtpUpload sub like the one on msdn but only with a few changes (instead of a filename I use the string)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx#Y3024

The result of this is that the file beeing uploaded get's the last bytes cut off. 
When I see the source code of that file on the server, it misses the <\html> tag.
i have debugged the code and the string created on the doc.save() is correct, then in the upload routine, when i use the getBytes() it's still correct, and the requestStream write method writes the correct length of the stream.
I can't figure out what's happening with this code.

Can anyone help me figuring this out?

Here's the code:

```
Dim outStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(str))
Dim uploader As AsynchronousFtpUpLoader = New AsynchronousFtpUpLoader
uploader.startUpload(pag, outStream)
```

And the class:

Public Class AsynchronousFtpUpLoader

```
Public Sub startUpload(ByVal pag As FtpPage, ByVal stream As Stream)
    Try
        Dim waitObject As ManualResetEvent

        Dim target As New Uri(pag.currentUrl)
        Dim state As New FtpState()
        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(target), FtpWebRequest)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
        request.UseBinary = False
        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(pag.login, pag.password)

        state.Request = request
        state.stream = stream
        ' Get the event to wait on.
        waitObject = state.OperationComplete

        ' Asynchronously get the stream for the file contents.
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf EndGetStreamCallback), state)

        ' Block the current thread until all operations are complete.
        waitObject.WaitOne()

        ' The operations either completed or threw an exception. 
        If state.OperationException IsNot Nothing Then
            Throw state.OperationException
        Else

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

Private Shared Sub EndGetStreamCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim state As FtpState = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, FtpState)

    Dim requestStream As Stream = Nothing

    Try
        requestStream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar)

        Const bufferLength As Integer = 2048
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(bufferLength) {}
        Dim readBytes As Integer = 0
        Dim stream As MemoryStream = state.stream
        Do
            readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
            If readBytes <> 0 Then
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes)
            End If
        Loop While readBytes <> 0

        requestStream.Flush()
        state.stream.Close()
        requestStream.Close()
        state.Request.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf EndGetResponseCallback), state)
    Catch e As Exception
        state.OperationException = e
        state.OperationComplete.[Set]()
        Return
    End Try

End Sub

Private Shared Sub EndGetResponseCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim state As FtpState = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, FtpState)
    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = Nothing
    Try
        response = DirectCast(state.Request.EndGetResponse(ar), FtpWebResponse)
        response.Close()
        state.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription
        state.OperationComplete.[Set]()
    Catch e As Exception
        state.OperationException = e
        state.OperationComplete.[Set]()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: can you post the code for uploading? where you call getBytes() etc... (Of course leaving out any urls)